# Pivot results in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have four tables (Oracle):

```
party
----------------
key

person
----------------
party_key | name

organization
----------------
party_key | name

id
----------------
party_key | id (varchar)
```

In the 'id' table there are multiple (more than 1) 'id's per organization and one per person (not my business/data model design -- no control over this).

So this sql query:

```
SELECT pers.name as person_name, org.name as org_name, id_pers.id as person_id, id_org.id as org_id
FROM party part
INNER JOIN person pers ON pers.party_key = part.key
INNER JOIN organization org ON org.party_key = part.key
INNER JOIN id id_pers ON pers.party_key = id_pers.party_key
INNER JOIN id id_org ON pers.party_key = id_org.party_key
```

Produces this:

```
person_name |   org_name | person_id | org_id
       John | whitehouse |     00005 |   0001
       John | whitehouse |     00005 |   0002
   Samantha | whitehouse |     00007 |   0001
   Samantha | whitehouse |     00007 |   0002
       John |    library |     00005 |   0008
       John |    library |     00005 |   0009
   Samantha |    library |     00007 |   0008
   Samantha |    library |     00007 |   0009
```

But I would like a SQL query to produce something like this:

```
person_name |   org_name | person_id | org_id1 | org_id2
       John | whitehouse |     00005 |    0001 |    0002
   Samantha | whitehouse |     00007 |    0001 |    0002
       John |    library |     00005 |    0008 |    0009
   Samantha |    library |     00007 |    0008 |    0009
```

I think the solution involves `pivot` but I am not sure how to execute it.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] including DDL statements for your tables and DML statements for sample data that replicates your desired output.

Comment: Will it always be the case that you have 1 or 2 org's per row?  Could there be 3?  And if so, how do you want to handle that?  *(Note, if this is for presentation to a human, do it in your presentation layer.  SQL isn't the best or the right place for manipulating data for presentation.)*

Comment: Also, I don't see how your query produces different values in the `person_id` column and the `org_id` column.  Every table is joined on the party key...  If you start with `party.key = '0001'` then the rows in `pers` and `org` will both have `party_key = '0001'`.  Which means that the rows in `id_pers` and `id_org` will also both have `party_key = '0001'`.  They're just aliases of the `id` table, so how do you get `'00005'` in `person_id` and `'0001'`,`'0002'` in `org_id`?  Have you over-simplified something here?

Answer (score 0):

Use min and max along with group by:

```
    select person_name, org_name,person_id, min(org_id), max(org_id)
    from 
   (SELECT pers.name as person_name, org.name as org_name, id_pers.id as person_id, id_org.id as org_id
FROM party part
INNER JOIN person pers ON pers.party_key = part.key
INNER JOIN organization org ON org.party_key = part.key
INNER JOIN id id_pers ON pers.party_key = id_pers.party_key
INNER JOIN id id_org ON pers.party_key = id_org.party_key)a
    group by person_name, org_name,person_id
```

Comment: The 'id' is a String, not a number. So min/max won't work.

Comment: "The 'id' is a String, not a number. So min/max won't work" min and max should also work fine on a string type to pivot @ryvantage

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f54a0dbdc4a8e043b2cbdbb333eb9dca - check @RaymondNijland... it will work in oracle also and i forgot to build in oracle

Comment: Will min/max work if there are 3 ids for org? or 4, 5, etc. ?

Comment: yes, it will - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4dd1a393260421f31ffc6fea08c006e2

Comment: "dbfiddle.uk/… - check @RaymondNijland... it will work in oracle also and i forgot to build in oracle " i know it works i already comment it to ryvantage you know.. i made the comment because you used the wrong DMBS.

Comment: @fa06 It will not be able to extract the 2nd of 3 items using `MIN` and `MAX` but it would be able to pick out the least or greatest.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, thank u , but it was mistakenly done on that time - sorry if  i sound rude

Comment: "It will not be able to extract the 2nd of 3 items using MIN and MAX but it would be able to pick out the least or greatest." indeed @MT0 to get the 2, 3 items you need to use `ROWNUM` or `ROW_NUMBER()` instead.. But to cross DBMS pivot always involves `MIN` or `MAX` in combination with `GROUP BY` you don't have to use `ROW_NUMBER`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your table structure and always joining on `party_key` works... but here is how to use a `PIVOT` (you first have to assign each organisation id a row number using the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5feb1/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE party ( key ) AS
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE person (party_key, name ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'John'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Samantha' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE organization ( party_key, name ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'Whitehouse' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Library'    FROM DUAL;


CREATE TABLE id ( party_key, id ) AS
  SELECT 1, '0001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '0002' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT pers.name as person_name,
         org.name as org_name,
         id_pers.id as person_id,
         id_org.id as org_id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY pers.name, org.name, id_pers.id
           ORDER BY id_org.id
         ) AS rn
  FROM   party part
         INNER JOIN person pers ON pers.party_key = part.key
         INNER JOIN organization org ON org.party_key = part.key
         INNER JOIN id id_pers ON pers.party_key = id_pers.party_key
         INNER JOIN id id_org ON pers.party_key = id_org.party_key
)
PIVOT ( MAX( org_id ) FOR rn IN (
  1 AS org_id1,
  2 AS org_id2
) )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5feb1/4/0)**:

```
| PERSON_NAME |   ORG_NAME | PERSON_ID | ORG_ID1 | ORG_ID2 |
|-------------|------------|-----------|---------|---------|
|        John |    Library |      0001 |    0001 |    0002 |
|        John |    Library |      0002 |    0001 |    0002 |
|        John | Whitehouse |      0001 |    0001 |    0002 |
|        John | Whitehouse |      0002 |    0001 |    0002 |
|    Samantha |    Library |      0001 |    0001 |    0002 |
|    Samantha |    Library |      0002 |    0001 |    0002 |
|    Samantha | Whitehouse |      0001 |    0001 |    0002 |
|    Samantha | Whitehouse |      0002 |    0001 |    0002 |
```